# Optimal pattern for parsing delimited (e.g. new line) network stream

Tags: design-patterns, parsing

I am looking for optimal for maintenance/easy of programming and elegant patterns to parse delimited network streams, e.g. protocols like SMTP. Some of the concerns I've always had are:

- how to react when a recv(2) call returns 0 - the need to track state to determine if no data has arrived or no more data will arrive
- what if in one packet, we have multiple delimited fields arriving (e.g. HTTP request/response headers)

I've usually ended up building a buffer and parsing buffer until delimiter, handling that then separately, but it's always inelegant. Is there a Knuth-ian or GOF solution that is elegant?

By optimal/elegant I mean maintenance/programmability rather than hard-core use.

Comment: What are you optimising for and how do you define "elegant"?

Answer (score 2):

Asking for "optimal" is, in a word, nonsensical. As @MetaFight asked, what are you optimizing and what is elegant?

**Optimal**

- Readability
- Speed
- Robustness
- Lines of code

and a number of other things.

**Design Patterns**

- Finite State Machine - implement as a set of hierarchical state machines
- Lexer/Parser - this is a specific type of hierarchical state machines which is often supported by code generation libraries, such as yacc/lex, bison, etc.
- State Monad - Another implementation of state machine patterns.

**Elegance**

An open-ended question with lots of personal taste thrown in. Personally, I would start with an implementation in Scala, using a State Monad approach, with `Either` values that allow capturing error information to help reporting and recovery. Your mileage may vary (YMMV).